# Error in implementing Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: python

I am getting an error in implementing 'Sieve of Eratosthenes' to get all the prime numbers between a specified range. I know my code is does not yet have primality checks, I will add them once I resolve the error.

```
def foo(l,r):
    if l == r:
        return "Error"
    if l > r:
        return "Error"
    if l < r:
        pool = set(xrange(l,r + 1))
        prime = 2
        if l == 1:
            print "Discard 1 for now"
        while prime <= r:
            rem = set(xrange(prime,r + 1,prime))
            pool.difference_update(rem)
            a = 0

            while prime >= pool[a]:
                a = a + 1
            prime = pool[a]
        print pool

foo(1,31623)
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\code\sieve_of_eratothenes.py", line 32, in <module>
    foo(1,31623)
  File "D:\code\sieve_of_eratothenes.py", line 27, in foo
    while prime >= pool[a]:
TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing
```

Comment: For an example of using `set` to do a sieve: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9302299/5987

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reference a set element by index, however a `set` is iterable, so this:

```
a = 0
while prime >= pool[a]:
   a = a + 1
   prime = pool[a]
```

can be rewritten as:

```
for el in pool:
   if prime >= el:
       prime = el
       break
```

Comment: +1. And if you need the index for some reason, you can do "for a, el in enumerate(pool)". But it's worth pointing out that, although this solves his error, it doesn't make his algorithm work. As BrenBam pointed out, the elements of a set are unordered, but the OP seems to think he'll get the smallest primes first.

Answer (score 2):

The error is just what it says: sets don't support the retrieval of individual items via indexing.  It looks like you want to use a list or xrange object instead (e.g., `pool = xrange(l, r+1)`.  Why did you use a set?

Note that the elements in the set are *unordered*, so iterating over them the way you're trying to do won't work.  You can't assume the bigger primes will be at the "end" of the set.

Comment: I used the set so that I can directly difference out the multiples of the prime from pool of numbers.