# Having a try at computing the sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: python

I'm an absolute novice to python but I am trying to compute something that should act like the sieve of Eratosthenes.

I'm going to start easy and just create a set with all integers from 2 up to 100. Let's call that set S.

I then want to create a set of all integers n such that 2n is contained in that set, let's call it P1. In other words, a set of the integers 2, 4, 6, 8 etc.

I want to then do the same thing but with P2 = 3n and then P3 = 5n.

In the end I want to return all integers of my set S but disregard the integers in P1, P2 and P3.

How would I go on about doing this?

My try:

```
  numbers=set(range(2,100))
```

but I'm stuck on creating the other sets and disregarding them!

Thanks.

My idea so far:

```
def sieve(n):
    S = set(range(2, 100))
    P1 = set(range(0, 100, 2))
    P2 = set(range(0, 100, 3))
    P3 = set(range(0, 100, 5))
    P5 = set(range(0, 100, 7))
    return S-P1-P2-P3-P5
print (sieve(100))
```

Comment: Try `range(2, 100, 2)`, `range(3, 100, 3)`, etc. The third parameter is the step.

Comment: And how do I discard the sets?

Comment: Substracting the sets. `S - P1` etc.

Comment: Ok cool, what exactly does range(2,100,2) mean? I realize that (2,100) means from 2 to 100...What is the extra ,2 for?

Comment: @user3200098 Try typing `help(range)` into your interpreter. This gives you the following information: "Returns a virtual sequence of numbers from start to stop by step.". Which is to say, it steps by 2 at a time, so that you get the numbers 2, 4, 6, ..., 96, 98.

Comment: Hey guys, if you could take a look at the code I posted and tell me why the sequence goes haywire when I try to remove the 7 step set, that would be great.

Comment: The problem is that you are using a `set`, which is not ordered. I do not know why the numbers _are_ ordered until you remove `P5`, but that's the "natural" way for a `set` to look. If you want them ordered, use `sorted(sieve(100))`, which will create an ordered `list` from the `set`.

Comment: Where can I post the code? I am still having a problem. Using sorted(sieve(100)) prints nothing.

Comment: Did you try `print(sorted(sieve(100)))`? Sorry if that was not clear...

Comment: Sorry, one more question and my naive sieve should work. I'm trying to collect the elements that got left out but were still primes (2,3,5,7)...How do I create a set of integers like that? I tried set(2,3,5,7) but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The easiest way would be to not have them in the set you subtract. Instead of `range(0,100,x)` use `range(x*x,100,x)`. Otherwise you could add back in `set([2,3,5,7])`. P.S. have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301781/fastest-in-term-of-space-way-to-find-prime-numbers-with-python

Answer (score 0):

Here a snippet with answering your specific question (not the whole sieve):

```
S = set(range(2, 101)) #numbers 2 to 100
P1 = set(range(2, 101, 2)) #2n
P2 = set(range(3, 101, 3)) #3n
P3 = set(range(5, 101, 5)) #5n
print ('S = ', S)
print ('P1 = ', P1)
print ('P2 = ', P2)
print ('P3 = ', P3)
S = S - P1 - P2 - P3 #Here comes the "discarding"
print ('S = ', S)
```

Obviously you won't want to hardcode your Px sets, and you will want to identify the next primer by looking at the next unsieved number.

Comment: My code works fine until I do a P4 = set(range(0, 100, 7)) then the whole sequence is screwed. How come? Isn't it just supposed to remove 7, 14, 21 etc?

Comment: It should be range(7, 100, 7) and not range(0, 100, 7).

Answer (score 0):

The [`range`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) function accepts a third parameter: The step. For example, `range(2, 10, 3)` is `[2, 5, 8]`. You can use this to build sets of multiples of some number, e.g. `range(3, 100, 3)` for the multiples of 3 smaller than 100, including 3 itself.

Combine those with the `-` operator on sets to build a first, naive version of the sieve:

```
p = set(range(2, 100))
for i in range(2, 10):
    p = p - set(range(i, 100, i))
print sorted(p)
```

However, this will also remove the tested `i`s themselved, thus lacking the first few primes:

```
[11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, ...]
```

Fixing this algorithm is left as an excercise to the reader. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

might try this:

```
def filter_primes(alist, newlist):
    for x in alist[1:]:
        if x%alist[0] != 0:
            newlist.append(x)
    return newlist

alist = range(2, 100)
sieve_list = []
primes = [2]

while len(alist) > 1:
    a = filter_primes(alist, sieve_list)
    primes.append(a[0])
    alist = sieve_list
    sieve_list = []

print primes

Out[1]:  [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 
67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

Should work for any number, not just 100.